# symfony2 file upload

Tags: upload, symfony

I've followed this guide : http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/file.html

and tested the sample here

However when I try the code, I have an error :

```
Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\Form\Form::move()
```

This is happening with the line :

```
$form['attachment']->move($dir, $someNewFilename);
```

I wonder why there is this error ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I finally found the solution

the doc is wrong

instead of :

```
$form['attachment']->move($dir, $someNewFilename);
```

it should be :

```
$form['attachment']->getData()->move($dir, $someNewFilename);
```

Comment: Using Symfony 2.7 (within Silex), I'm currentlly finding that ->getData() returns just the string of the filename, so ->move() etc. don't work on it.

Comment: Ah, I had a hardcoded <form> tag and hadn't added the enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute to it; adding that returns me the UploadedFile object instead of a string!

Answer (score 18):

This doesn't use the 'Form' class, but I have had success retrieving uploads directly from the request:

```
/* @var Request */
$request = $this->getRequest();

/* @var UploadedFile */
$uploadedFile = $request->files->get('upfile'); //upfile must be the value of the name attribute in the <input> tag
if (null === $uploadedFile)
    return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('_upload_index'));

/* @var string*/
$filename = $uploadedFile->getPathname();
```

Answer (score 5):

Now it's better to do as explained in the official documentation :
http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html